# Character " " as 0

Tags: java

I currently have a method which goes through a plain text file and I need it to account `" "` as `0`.

At the moment it takes a blank area and represents it as `-1`.

Here's my code.

```
    int[][] board = new int[9][9];


        File file = new File ("zero.sud");
        FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(file);
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
        StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
        String newline;
        while ((newline = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            stringBuffer.append(newline);
            //stringBuffer.append("\n"); ALREADY DECLARING IT.
        }
        fileReader.close();
        String data =  stringBuffer.toString();
        int counting = data.length();
        int counter = 0;

        int i,j;

        for(i = 0; i<9; i++) {
            for (j =0; j < 9-1; j++) {

                int numbers = Character.getNumericValue(data.charAt(counter));
                counter++;
                board[i][j] = numbers;

            }

        }
```

I have tried an `if` statement, but I can't get it to work.

Comment: " j < 9-1" I guess you want  j < i-1

Comment: Oh right, sorry - that wasn't even in my code. Having to use Xming at the moment!

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: I'm guessing you want [`Integer.parseInt()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String)) rather than [`Character.getNumericValue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#getNumericValue(char))

Comment: And what can't you get to work? I don't see anything in your code that does (or does not) what you seem to be asking about.

Comment: How do you _know_ it doesn't work? I'm not questioning if it works or not -- I trust that you know it doesn't work, but if _I_ don't know _how_ to know if it works or not, _I_ cannot actually help you, can I?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can tell, you want a blank space to be represented as a 0, but `Character.getNumericValue(data.charAt(counter))` represents a blank space as a -1.  Try this (assuming your code works in all other cases thus the else):

```
char ch = data.charAt(counter)

if (ch == ' ') 
    board[i][j] = 0;
else
    board[i][j] = Character.getNumericValue(ch);

counter++;
```

Note, this is why you are getting -1:

> This method returns the numeric value of the character, as a nonnegative int value; -2 if the character has a numeric value that is not a nonnegative integer; -1 if the character has no numeric value.

from http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/character_getnumericvalue.htm